# Find word in a text and make founded words in a text bold and color:red

Tags: javascript, html

Cant get how to change style of founded word,i know two ways how to find,like with indexof and regex but how to change style with founded index or etc?So if shortly i want to do smthing like that:
words to find:
osq,kkw
Text:
aaa bbb **osq** **osq**qjweqj **kkw**

```
 $(".findwords").click(function()
{
    var text = $("#text").val();
    var words = $("#words").val();
    var arrword = words.split(',');
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend:function()
        {
            $("#lback-words").show();
            $("#lback-text").show();
            $('.loader').show();
        },
        url: "/Demo2/Fwords/",
        data: data = { "text": text, "words": words },
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#text').val(' ');
            $('#words').val(' ');
            setTimeout("$('.loader').hide()", 3000);
            setTimeout("$('#lback-words').hide()", 3000);
            setTimeout("$('#lback-text').hide()", 3000);
            console.log(data);
            var sub_ul = $('<ul/>');
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                console.log(value);
                var sub_li = $('<li/>');
                $(sub_li).html(value.w + "-" + value.q);
                $(sub_li).appendTo(sub_ul);
            });
            var appendContent = $("<section class='searchresult'><h4>Result:</h4><div class='words'>Words:</div><div class='text'>Text:<br>" + text + "</div></section>");
            $(appendContent).find(".words").append(sub_ul);
            $(".texnwords").append(appendContent);
        },
        error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
})
```

Comment: How do you make that words bold? Inside span with some css? Strong tag? Post a bit of your code.

Comment: thats my appendcontent dunno how to do it better make add some span or?  var appendContent = $("<section class='searchresult'><h4>Result:</h4><div class='words'>Words:</div><div class='text'>Text:<br>" + text + "</div></section>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var html = $('.your_text_element').html();
html  = html.replace('osq', '<b>osq</b>');
$('.your_text_element').html(html);
```

update:

```
// get values of text and words
var text = $("#text").val();
var words = $("#words").val();
// check if text contains words
var text_after_check = text.replace( words, '<b>' + words + '</b>');
if( text != text_after_check ){
    // words found
    // add html with hightlighted text to div check_result
    $('#check_result').html(text_after_check);
    // hide textarea (optional)
    $("#text").toggle();        
}
```

In yout html add the div with id = check_result

Comment: m8 work but can i ask how to do it with vals,if i have like that: var text = $("#text").val();
        var words = $("#words").val();
        var arrword = words.split(',');   and i need to do this thing for every word from arrword.

Comment: Do you mean you need highlight text inside input fields?

Comment: i mean that i have input and textarea,then i click button and it append a result of find as a section with divs one for a words another for text,and this one where is text i need to change like,making bold and red words if they exist in a text.

Comment: You can not change style of part of input fields. As a solution - you can create a new div and put the result there on clicking button. For better understanding, post your code.

Comment: i added part of code from taking vals from input and textarea till end of ajax where i append dom for adding a result..Hope you will understand what i wanna do now.I mean i just need change *text* val to make all words that exist in text bold and red.